# how to get last inserted date in php MYSQL

Tags: php

I have two tables, and I want to get the last enterd date.

The first table is `seeker`:

```
seeker_nic-----username
111-------------ali
222-------------umer
333-------------raza
```

The second one is `requestblood`:

```
id-------seeker_nic-----requireddate
1-------  111 ----------2012/10/9
2 ------- 222-----------2012/5/8
3 ------  111-----------2012/12/12
4 ------- 111-----------2012/11/12
5---------111-----------2012/09/09
6 ------- 222-----------2012/7/9
7 ------- 333 ----------2012/4/4
```

Now, I want to list the users one time with their last inserted date like..

```
s.no---- username----- requireddate
 1------- ali---------- 2012/09/09
 2------- umer--------- 2012/7/9
 3------- raza--------- 2012/4/4
```

I am using this query, but it shows maximum date not the latest one.

```
SELECT seeker.username, MAX(bloodrequest.requireddate) AS requireddate, COUNT(bloodrequest.requireddate) AS total
FROM seeker
JOIN bloodrequest
  ON seeker.seeker_nic = bloodrequest.seeker_nic
GROUP BY seeker.username
```

This shows the maximum date, and it shows total dates.  For example, 111 has total "4", but I don't know how to show the last inserted date... I am new in PHP, please help me.  :(

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please use proper punctuation and capitalization.  StackOverflow is not a text message.  Anyway, you want the last inserted date over all?   SELECT MAX(requireddate) FROM requestblood.

Comment: sorry.. Max shows the maximum date but i want the last inserted date.. @corbin

Comment: Oh you mean your literally want the date that a row was last inserted?  You'll have to store that then.  MySQL doesn't store information like that automatically.  Edit:  Actually MySQL might store that...  Edit: Looks like SHOW TABLE STATUS can be used, but it seems rather hacky to me.  I would add a new field to the table and then insert the current date into it whenever you insert records (you could use a TIMESTAMP and have it do it automatically with a default value).

Comment: thats why i put count in my query,, but i dont know how to store that count value and then echo the maximum count number.. :(

Comment: I'm confused now.  How is the maximum count related to the last insertion date?  Is requireddate guaranteed to the date of insertion?

Comment: i have used the TIMESTAMP too... but problem is I dont want specific user last inserted date.. i have to show list of all users and their last inserted date..

Comment: Then use a group by.  SELECT seeker_nic, MAX(date_field) as max_date FROM bloodrequest GROUP BY seeker_nic;

Comment: not maximum count... only count.. as in my query """" COUNT(bloodrequest.requireddate) AS total
FROM seeker"" when i run this in phpmyadmin,, it shows total numbers of date enterd by correspodings seeker_nnic

Answer (score 0):

Very simple but you will need to use subselect - acquire row with last id (this will work only if you have correct indexing - i suppose you have).

Example:

```
SELECT seeker_nic, username, 
(SELECT `requiredate` FROM `requestblood` WHERE `seeker_nic`=`seeker`.`seeker_nic` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1) as `last_requiredate`
FROM `seeker`
```